# How do I share photo with only one person instead of circle?

Tags: photo-sharing, google-photos

I've uploaded my photos to Google Photos and I want to share them with only one person. I don't want to use share-link, because it's visible for everyone who has it, isn't it? I cannot be sure that the person wouldn't forward it to someone else.

I'm looking for a way like Google Drive has. The photo should be visible only when the person is logged to Google account.

Is there a way how can I achieve that?

Comment: Create a temporary circle with only one person in it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are right. If you share a photo via link it would be visible for everyone who has the link.

You can share your photos with a specific person by following these steps:

From [Share a photo album](https://support.google.com/plus/answer/1407859?hl=en):

1. Open [Google+](https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=oz&passive=1209600&continue=https://plus.google.com/?gpsrc%3Dgplp0#identifier). Place your cursor in the top left corner for the Google+ main menu.
2. Click Photos icon **Photos** > **More** at the top of the page > **Albums**.
3. Click the album you wish to **share** > Share button at the top right.
4. Add your comments & **select who to share with**. You can share with someone who is not on Google+ by entering their email address in the To field.
5. Click Share.

Comment: It's less than a year, and this answer seems to already be OBE.  Either that, or my account doesn't allow this workflow.  When I click the drawer icon / "hamburger", there is no option for "**Photos**".  Come on, Google!

Comment: Google+ is dead. Can you modernize this answer?

Answer (score 0):

There is no technical way that you can prevent someone sharing a photo with others, if they're determined.

The other answer explains how you can share with a specific group of Google users (size of group, 1 or more).

But if a person you have shared with decides to screen-shot what they are seeing, they can save the image to some service (their own Google Photos, Flickr, Dropbox, etc) and share it with anyone they want - and there is **no** way that you can prevent this.

Comment: I know that, but I don't want to allow them to reshare photos so easily. Saving a screenshot is more complicated than posting a link.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the tool you know works? Add the photo to Google Drive and share the file from there.

Comment: Photos on Google Drive take space whereas on Google Photos they don't.

Comment: True, but we're talking about one file here, no? And you can always delete it after the other person has seen it.